# Ubuntu 12.10 : Eclipse closes automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Eclipse closes automatically with out any error messages, either in the eclipse log or command line.

I was using Eclipse Juno and then switched to Kepler after reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206182/eclipse-juno-4-2-1-crashes-frequently-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu12-10-from-12-0) post.

I have also switched from OpenJDK to Oracle Java.

The message in command line is [debug] execute contextualize

```
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
```

And in the log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2013-04-13 18:13:39.232
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2013-04-13 18:13:39.232
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+D:
Binding(CTRL+D,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.eof,EOF,
    Send end of file,
    Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
    org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@508b0f99,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.debug.ui.console,,,system)
  Binding(CTRL+D,
ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.delete.line,Delete Line,
    Delete a line of text,
    Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.textEditor,Text Editing,Text Editing   Commands,true),
    org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@59ad2f1e,
    ,,true),null),
org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope,,,system)
!SESSION 2013-04-13 18:29:20.228 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130314-1330
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-04-13 18:29:30.276
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

Btw, this error doesn't come in the log everytime eclipse closes.

I am using following eGit and m2e

Well I have this error in log too. But not sure if this is causing the problem.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /icons/m2.gif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 4.2/Juno doesn't work well with your Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse 4.3/Kepler isn't finished yet. What about going one step back to Eclipse 3.8?

I personally like the Springsource Tool Suite which is currently available in two flavours (based on Eclipse 4.2 and based on Eclipse 3.8). Maybe the 3.8 based STS works for you. Even if you don't need the Eclipse add-ons that are already bundled with STS, this may be a good solution for you until either Ubuntu 13.04 or Eclipse 4.3 is released.

You can find STS here: http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts

Comment: emmm.. looks like the only solution. I haven't used STS yet. May be I should give a try.